# Multiple Schema.org Product items & how will it look like in search engine result?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have implemented the `Product` Schema.org type similar to this on one single page:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"> <span itemprop="name">Test name 1</span> <img src="test1.jpg" /> <span itemprop="description">Description test 1</span> <span itemprop="sku">#001</span> </div>  

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"> <span itemprop="name">Test name 2</span> <img src="test2.jpg" /> <span itemprop="description">Description test 2</span> <span itemprop="sku">#002</span> </div> 

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"> <span itemprop="name">Test name 3</span> <img src="test3.jpg" /> <span itemprop="description">Description test 3</span> <span itemprop="sku">#003</span> </div>
```

So, I am wondering whether this is okay to have three `Product` schemas in one page. And how it will look like on Google Search engine results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s perfectly fine to have multiple `Product` items on one page. This is even pretty common, for example for category or search pages listing several products.

What Google Search does or does not do with this markup may change at any point. Their documentation is at https://developers.google.com/structured-data/. It seems they currently don’t offer a Rich Snippet for product lists ([their Product Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) is [only for pages about a single product](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/85429/17633)).

Comment: So, basically you would recommend to use the separate page for each product rather than one page for all, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @babyghost: Well, for various reasons (like usability and SEO) it’s a good idea to have a single page per product. But that doesn’t mean that you shouldn’t also have pages with lists of products (each "teaser" links to its full page via the `url` property).

Comment: @babyghost What about cross selling product in a product page ? Do the need to have schema on it ?